# Is there a $\triangle ABC$, with $D$ on $BC$, such that $AB$, $BC$, $CA$, $AD$, $BD$, $CD$ are all integers, but only one is even?

Tags: geometry, number-theory, trigonometry, triangles, diophantine-equations

This is just a question I came up with while working through another problem.

> If we have a triangle $ABC$ and we draw a cevian from $A$ to $D$ on side $BC$, is it possible to assign integer values to lengths $AB$, $BC$, $AC$, $AD$, $BD$ or $CD$ such that only one of the listed lengths has an even valued length? If it is possible, what are these lengths?

I have done some parts of this problem on my own. I figured out that this even length could only be $BC$, $CD$, or $BD$, with $BD$ and $CD$ being the same case.

With $BC$ being the only even length I computed for $BC$ using Stewart's Theorem and got
$$BC = \frac{(AC^2)(BD)+(AB^2)(CD)}{(BD)(CD)+(AD)^2}$$ where every length but $BC$ is odd. The equation seems to work but I don't know how to obtain its integer solutions.

Similarly with $BD$/$CD$ case, I applied Stewart's theorem and got $$BD=\frac{(AB^2)(CD)-(BC)(AD^2)}{(CD)(BC)-(AC)^2}$$
Once again this seems to work, but I don't know how to obtain its integer solutions.

Pretty much all I need help is verifying whether or not my work is right, and if it  is how to find the integer solutions of my provided equations. If there is a better way or my work has flaws please let me know.

Comment: since BD+CD=BC, either one of BD or CD is even, or BC is even, so there are two basic cases that can be used.

Comment: I’m not sure if this could work, but maybe Pythagorean triples are a special case of the integer triples of a triangle, like maybe there’s a term with $sin\theta$ and $cos\theta$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ makes those terms look invisible, so trying to generalize Pythagorean triples to non-right triangles might work

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution found by brute force (by setting $AD=AB$):
[image]

and three more interesting ones found by exhaustive search:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Almost right ... I mean the triangles ( angle $\approx 92^{\circ}$)  --- the answer is lovely!

Comment: How did you compute for these cases? Also what about the cases for which the even length isn't the whole side length? Are there any triangles that satisfy the second equation listed above?

Comment: Of interest:  All the triangles with their dividing lines include a 60° angle.

Comment: ABD equilateral with AB=5, with DC=3 and AC=7.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment but here is food for thought.

It would appear, incorrectly, that we can find what you need if we join two dissimilar Pythagorean triples on a matching side-A. This side and be any odd number greater than one. We begin with Euclid' formula here shown as.

$$A=m^2-k^2,\quad B=2mk,\quad C=m^2+k^2$$
If we solve the A-function for k, we can find triples that match a length "A" by testing a finite range of m-values to see which ones yield integers.

\begin{equation}
A=m^2-k^2\implies k=\sqrt{m^2-A}\qquad\text{for}\qquad  \lfloor\sqrt{A+1}\rfloor \le m \le \frac{A+1}{2}
\end{equation}
The lower limit ensures $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and the upper limit ensures $m> k$.
$$A=15\implies \lfloor\sqrt{15+1}\rfloor=4\le m \le \frac{15+1}{2} =8\quad\land\quad m\in\{4,8\}\implies k \in\{1,7\} $$
$$F(4,1)=(15,8,17)\qquad \qquad F(8,7)=(15,112,113) $$

If these two are joined at side-A, we have an acute triangle with sides $$(17,113,120)$$ with a cevian $(15)$ going from the $(17,113)$ vertex to the. 120-side, splitting it into lengths of $8$ and $112$. Unfortunately, this yields $3$ even lengths. If we were to join the even sides of two triples such as

$$(5,12,13)\qquad (35,12,37)$$ we would have $(13,37,40)$ with $40$ split into $(5,35)$. That would still leave two even lengths: the base $(40)$ and the cevian $(12)$. This probably eliminates Pythagorean triples from the solution. There are methods of finding integer cevians in a right triangle from a non-right vertex to an adjacent side but the question remains about the split-length of the target side being integers.

Comment: Although very tempting a solution, there cannot be any right angles there it seems, just because of Pythagoras.

Comment: @ orangeskid I was not suggesting that the cevian be a right angles. I was indicating that a right angled cevian would not work and that another could be found by trig that escapes me right now. A "new" cevian length, longer than the altitude could be tried and then the lengths of the base segments could be evaluated to see if the are odd integers.

Comment: I see.  Now, it seems from the solution of Jack D'Aurizio, he was looking for two triangles with odd integral sides , one common side, and two angles summing up to $\pi$. That would give an equality for $\cos$, and  solutions were found by computer search, I wonder if there is a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to Heron's formula, area and semi-perimeter are given as follows.
Sides a,b and c.
$Area=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$
$s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$

We consider the case of $AB=AD$.
Let $a=AB, b=AC, c=BC, a=AD, c1=BD, c2=DC$.

Let apply Heron's formula to triangle $(ABC, ABD, ADC)$.

Triangle $ABC$:
$s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$
$Area=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$
$c2=c-c1$

Triangle $ABD$:
$s1=\frac{2a+c1}{2}$
$Area1=\sqrt{s1(s1-a)(s1-a)(s1-c1)}$

Triangle $ADC$:
$s2=\frac{a+b+c2}{2}$
$Area2=\sqrt{s2(s2-a)(s2-b)(s2-c2)}$

$Area=Area1+Area2.$
\begin{split}
 \sqrt{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)} &= c1\sqrt{(2a+c1)(2a-c1)} \\
                                     &+ \sqrt{(c1-a-b-c)(a-b-c+c1)(a-b+c-c1)(a+b-c+c1)}  
 \end{split}

By simple algebra, we know that equation $Area-Area1-Area2=0$ has a factor $-cc1+a^2-b^2+c^2$.
Thus problem was reduced to finding the integer solutions of $-cc1+a^2-b^2+c^2=0$.
We found the integer solutions of $-cc1+a^2-b^2+c^2=0$ with $(a,b,c)<30$.
Jack D'Aurizio's solutions are included.
Similarly, we can apply this method to general case.

```
            [a  b  c  c1 c2] 

            [ 3  7  8  3  5]
            [ 5  7  8  5  3]
            [ 5  9  8  1  7]
            [ 5 13 16  7  9]
            [ 5 23 24  3 21]
            [ 7 15 16  5 11]
            [ 7 17 16  1 15]
            [ 7 19 24 11 13]
            [ 9 11  8  3  5]
            [ 9 15 16  7  9]
            [ 9 17 16  3 13]
            [ 9 21 24  9 15]
            [11 13 16 13  3]
            [11 17 24 17  7]
            [11 19 16  1 15]
            [11 23 24  7 17]
            [11 25 24  3 21]
            [13 15  8  1  7]
            [13 17 24 19  5]
            [13 23 24  9 15]
            [13 25 24  5 19]
            [15 21 24 15  9]
            [15 27 24  3 21]
            [17 19 24 21  3]
            [17 23 16  1 15]
            [17 29 24  1 23]
            [19 21 16 11  5]
            [19 23 24 17  7]
            [19 25 24 13 11]
            [23 29 24 11 13]
            [25 29 24 15  9]
            [27 29 16  9  7]
```